# unable to mouseover in headless with Xvfb using java selenium webdriver

Tags: java, webdriver, mouseover, silent, xvfb

Does java Webdriver mouseover work in headless silent mode (none GUI display)? 
I have this code that works when run in FF headless GUI mode BUT doesn't work when run in non-GUI mode (via Xvfb frame buffer).

FF 17.0.8
Selenium 2.33.0
Java Selenium WebDriver

I need to hover to a menu then click on an option from the submenu. Again, This works in headless GUI mode but does NOT work in headless silent (non-GUI) mode :(. How to debug in silent mode?

```
mainMenu = BaseWebDriver.driver.findElement(By.linkText("Copy"));
Actions builder = new Actions(BaseWebDriver.driver);
builder.moveToElement(mainMenu).build().perform();  //perform mouse hover
//click on the option on submenu
BaseWebDriver.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='__content']/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[6]/ul/li[2]/a")).click();
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!!
-Terry

Answer (score -1):

install xvfb using "sudo apt-get install xvfb"
Try running your script using "xvfb-run --auto-servernum"
Im using python with selenium and it worked for me, i ran the script like "xvfb-run --auto-servernum python test.py".

If the site you are testing is an public site means share the url, people will try on the same and give you solutions.